# Do I lose rep if a question is automatically closed?

Tags: discussion, reputation

It seems that I've lost 100 reputation; presumably this is because an answer of mine has been automatically closed after a certain number of downvotes. **The answer was CW**, which I had assumed would not affect my rep, it was a non-serious joke answer to an `offtopic` question: **why has this cost me 100 rep?**

*PS. I've googled and searched on this site and can't find any reference to losing points like this. I may also be wrong as [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow/11741#11741) states quite clearly that voting on a CW post should not affect rep.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What was your answer?

If it was flagged as spam enough times, it comes with a penalty of -100 reputation.

As George Stocker pointed out, the -100 reputation penalty also comes with the offensive, abusive, or hate speech flags.

Comment: Or if it's flagged as offensive, abusive, or hate speech.

Comment: @George Stocker, right you are. I was searching for a FAQ entry on flag reasons, but couldn't find one, so I just went off memory. Which on a Friday afternoon, is just gone.

Comment: Well, the answer has been removed so I can't link to it. Last time I checked, it had been marked offensive twice (and the question was closed). It had a very weak swearword in it, referencing the movie *Airplane!* Some people on SO have quite literally no sense of humour.

Comment: And if happens if you were the last person to edit said post, if I recall correctly. And oxbow, sadly you are correct about some folks having no sense of humor. (Speaking of, whatever happened to Meta Friday ... ?)

Comment: Last I looked (an hour or two ago), that particular answer was sitting at 3 offensive and 1 spam vote, so this is exactly what happened.

Comment: @John Rudy: No, the rep hit now applies to the original poster, not the last editor.

Comment: I wouldnt say 100 rep is a penalty, but -100 rep is a penalty. So i changed the post

Comment: My dear viking, a -100$ loss is a gain.

Comment: @mmeyers: Thank you, very glad to hear that, now that I've turned into an edit freak ... :)

Comment: @oxbow_lakes:  Some people on any reasonably large net forum will have absolutely no sense of humor, and I don't see this changing.    Saying things that are likely to offend people on the forum just to make a joke is asking for trouble.  Unfortunate but true.