# Where did my rep go?

Tags: support, reputation

According to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation, I lost a lot of rep in the 10hrs this day is old in Greenwich:

`** rep today: -102`

According to the rep page, this is due to -100 to question 105897, which doesn't exist. Of course, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/133368/sbi?tab=reputation makes no mention of this.

So where did my rep go?

Comment: It looks like you were hit with a spam/offensive flag deletion which removes 100 reputation as well as deleting the post.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28895/do-i-lose-rep-if-a-question-is-automatically-closed/28896#28896) helps ...

Comment: As ChrisF already mentioned, the -100 rep looks suspiciously like the effect of an offensive/spam flagged post that was removed. A spam/offensive flag also carries an automatic downvote, so a mod-superflag would result in -102 rep, as far as I understand the flag mechanism.

Comment: Dropping the F bomb in a recent question you asked probably had _a lot_ to do with it. Profanity turns almost any post into flypaper for flags.

Comment: @Fabian: No, the -2 are explained by me downvoting two answers. It's the -100 I was after.

Comment: Lemme just add this: Removing rep from a user - for whatever reason I don't want to go into in this comment - but not showing this on the user's rep timeline reeks. Badly.

Comment: I also "lost" nearly 100 on question that got about 14 upvotes and was zapped by Jeff. So I'm totally with you on this matter..

Comment: @Shadow: Never mind the rep, but his reaction is complete nonsense. If Jeff objected (as hilarious as this is in itself) to the use of that word in a phrase that was not directed at anyone, he could have just edited the question and move one. There are certainly other ways to express what I said. (It just never occured to me to not to use the phrase that is, IME, most commonly used among the professionals who frequent this site). No, I think that question was deleted because Jeff he didn't didn't like what it said (rather than how), and those -100 were simply meant as a punishment.

Comment: In your case, it's the community fault not Jeff. As far as I remember, it takes five spam flags to mark post as spam, delete it and remove 100 rep, all automatically. I doubt that Jeff triggered this manually, more likely 5 members flagged your question.

Comment: @Shadow: As you see from the comments to Pekka's answer, not everyone reading the "offending" sentence it even noticed it. (It _is_ a common thing to say, after all.) So I think it would take rather a lot of users to gain five flags. But that question didn't have much time for users to even look at it, let alone read down far enough down to find the "offense". I doubt many ever noticed it, and even less of them will have flagged. Of course, I have no way to check, but the above leads me to seriously doubt it had enough flags besides Jeff's.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question was spam or offensive flagged, probably because of the use of the f word.

(Not that I would regard that flag-worthy in that specific context - *"...we f-ed up on this small detail..."*. Just stating the facts.)

Comment: @Lightness: The waking world does not have policies about what can be said between two people, except in the case of things like criminal harassment. When I speak to another person, I choose what I say.

Comment: @DeadMG: This is a website with policies and rules like any society. Again, I'm not saying that I do or do not agree with that policy that is in place. I have no intention of arguing over the _content_ of the policy, nor on whether or not it could be or should be enforced either way! Also note that I would not have flagged the post. I myself certainly enjoy some colourful language, as you know. But if one suggests that they are _incapable_ of selecting their words for any given situation, because of their upbringing, then that just seems weird to me. That's all *Shrug*.